# C++: cin, cout, etc. "does not name a type"

Tags: c++

having a problem with the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Calculator
{
  public:

  int Sum(int first, int second);
};

int Calculator::Sum(int first, int second)
{
  int sum = first + second;
  return sum;
}

class Printer{
public:
  void Print();
  int first, second, calculated_sum;

  cout << "Give a first integer: ";
  cin >> first;
  cout << "Give a second integer: ";
  cin >> second;

  Calculator calc;
  calc.Sum(first, second);
};

void Printer::Print(){
  cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Printer object;
  object.Print();
}
```

I can only touch Printer class, as the others are not created by me.

The errors I get when I try to compile this:

> code.cpp:22: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cout' with no type
>
> code.cpp:22: error: expected ';' before '<<' token
>
> code.cpp:23: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cin' with no type
>
> code.cpp:23: error: expected ';' before '>>' token
>
> code.cpp:24: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cout' with no type
>
> code.cpp:24: error: expected ';' before '<<' token
>
> code.cpp:25: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'cin' with no type
>
> code.cpp:25: error: expected ';' before '>>' token
>
> code.cpp:28: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'calc' with no type
>
> code.cpp:28: error: expected ';' before '.' token
>
> code.cpp: In member function 'void Printer::Print()':
>
> code.cpp:32: error: 'sum' was not declared in this scope

So lot's of errors for so few lines of code. Any ideas on what to try to fix this?

Comment: What exactly do you expect the code free-floating within your `Printer` class to do?

Comment: Statements are legal only inside a function definition; they can't appear at the top level of a class declaration.

Comment: Get a decent IDE and it will pick up these problems

Comment: None of those errors match the one in your title.

Comment: Doh, I followed the assignment instructions to the letter forgetting the basic things :D Being a Python scripter, I thought these issues were some C++ oddities but of course the same rules apply to Python... Thanks guys for pointing me the obvious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what people are saying in the comments.  You need to move

```
cout << "Give a first integer: ";
cin >> first;
cout << "Give a second integer: ";
cin >> second;
```

from sitting inside your class into some function.  The area inside a class declaration is for declaring member variables and methods.

Same goes for the lines

```
Calculator calc;
calc.Sum(first, second);
```

The print method of the Printer object, for example, seems like a good place to put these lines.

Then you just need to make sure you declare sum in the scope of the print method and you should be good to go.

Comment: This got me through the exercise, of course I should have known these already since I've dabbled with Python for quite many years. Thanks mate!